# Error when clicked a JButton - ActionEvent is not performed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jbutton

Here I have a GUI window and it basically ask the user to select a JRadioButton and type something in a JTextField, then choose confirm/cancel.

It is a project which we have to make a UML-to-Java text file. User would enter class information and choose a UML relationship, and this programme have to print out the Java clsas text on a JTextField. Just like when you create a new class in eclipse.

what I want to do is make a boolean[] to store an array of booleans, when user selects JRadioButton_A it'll store true and when user select JRadioButton_B it'll store false.And also I want the things typed in JTextField to be checked by a checkName(), if the method returns false, the string will be stored in an `ArrayList<String>`.

Below is my code - and the error is that when user clicked confirmButton, the programme just stopped and have no reaction. Also, there's some problems in getName() method and the boolean[] for storing true and false. When user needs to input name again, it would save the discarded sting/boolean into the array. Is there any better way to make this programme? I feel like I am complicating things and there should be a simpler way to make it.

Here's my UI class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddClass extends JFrame{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ClassName classObject = new ClassName();

private JRadioButton publicButton, privateButton;
private JLabel className;
private JTextField inputClassName;
private JButton confirmButton;
private JButton cancelButton;

public AddClass(){
    super("Add class");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    publicButton = new JRadioButton("public", true);
    privateButton = new JRadioButton("private", false);
    className = new JLabel("Class Name: ");
    inputClassName = new JTextField(10);
    confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");
    cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

    add(publicButton);      
    add(privateButton);     
    add(className);     
    add(inputClassName);        
    add(confirmButton);
    add(cancelButton);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(publicButton);
    group.add(privateButton);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
//      Handler2 handler2 = new Handler2();     
//      Handler3 handler3 = new Handler3();
    confirmButton.addActionListener(handler);
//      publicButton.addActionListener(handler2);
//      privateButton.addActionListener(handler3);
    }// end constructor AddClass()

private class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String name = inputClassName.getText();
        classObject.addName(name);
        while (classObject.checkName(name) == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class name invalid. " +
                    "\nEntered name should not contain java keywords or equal to other existing names. " +
                    "\nPlease try again."); // doesn't work
            name = input.nextLine();
            classObject.addName(name);
        }// end if
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class saved."); // doesn't work
        name = input.nextLine();
        classObject.addName(name);

    }// end actionPerformed()
}// end Handler class

private class Handler2 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        boolean b = true;
        b = classObject.setPP();
        }
    }

private class Handler3 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        boolean b = false;
        b = classObject.setPP();
        }
    }


}// end AddClass
```

Here's my class for storing user input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClassName {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
JavaKeywords keyObject = new JavaKeywords();

private ArrayList<String> className = new ArrayList<String>();
private String name = new String();
private int size = className.size();
private Boolean[] bArray = new Boolean[size];

public void addName(String name){
    this.name = name;
    className.add(name);
}// end addName()

public boolean checkName(String name){
    boolean check = true;
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++){
        if (keyObject.containsKeyword(className.get(i)) || name.equals(className.get(i))){

            boolean o = false;
            check = o;
        }// end if
    }// end for
    return check;
}// end checkName

public boolean setPP(){
    boolean b = true;
    return b;
}

public void addPP(Boolean[] bArray){
    this.bArray = bArray;
    for (int i=0; i>=size; i++){
        bArray[i] = setPP();
    }
}// add a Array of boolean. for className[i], its class type = item[i] in bArray. 
             // public = true, private = false
public String getPublicPrivate(){
    String p = "";
    for (int i =0; i<=size; i++){
        if(bArray[i]=true)
            p = "public";
        else
            p = "private";
    }
    return p;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}//end setName()

public String getName(){
    return name;
}// end getName()

public ArrayList<String> getAllNames(){
    return className;
}// end getAllNames()

public void setAllNames(ArrayList<String> className){
    this.className = className;
}// end setAllNames()

}//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your program "stops" when the user clicks the confirm button is that the program is waiting for input on the command line.  Specifically, your `input` variable is tied to `System.in` (i.e. command line).

You can just type your answer at the command line, hit Enter nad your program will continue.

OTOH, I suspect that using the command line is not what you want as you are using a GUI.  Instead you can add an input field (e.g. a JTextBox).

Comment: Thanks! I've just corrected that, and it continued for awhile until the **showMessageDialog** popped up. After i closed the message box, the programme "stops" again :(

Comment: The next line (`name = input.nextLine();`) still waits for input from the command line

Answer (score 0):

In the `ActionListener` for the confirm button the `Scanner` instance `input` in this statement blocks waiting on input from the user

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

The `ActionEvent` won't complete until a value has been entered.

Solution: Add a `JTextField` as an alternative means to read input from the user.

Comment: I just changed it to  **String name = inputClassName.getText();**
and the actionEvent is performed. But then I cannot close the window using the "x" on top right corner. The programme just stopped. Also the checkName() method doesn't work.... :( Please help?

Comment: 1) You need to call `setDefaultCloseOperation` for the `JFrame` 2) `checkName()` is outside the scope of this question - please post a new question